# How to connect with new Facebook C# SDK v5.0?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been using the old v3.0 C# SDK for some time and Facebook have decided to deprecate that API and also block it so I can no longer use it. I'm trying to upgrading to v5.0 but it seems a lot more different and I can't get it to authenticate.

All I need is a Facebook login button which people click, login and allow permissions to my app (which works) but then I want to be able to call `Get()` on the C# SDK in the code behind to get their friends. This is what I have in my aspx page which works fine to allow them to login:

```
<input type="button" id="fblogin" value="Login to Facebook" disabled="disabled"/>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'myappid',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    function facebooklogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user authorized
                // make sure to set the top.location instead of using 
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                // user cancelled
            }
        },
          {
            scope: 'publish_stream' 
          });
    };

    $(function() {
        // make the button is only enabled after the facebook js sdk has been loaded.
        $('#fblogin').attr('disabled', false).click(facebooklogin);
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());
```

However when I'm trying to connect to the Facebook client as below it throws an error which says

> (OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user."} System.Exception
>   {Facebook.FacebookOAuthException}

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(myappid, mysecretkey)
SomeDictionary object = client.Get("/me/friends");
```

What am I missing to get this active authtoken? How can I access it in the code behind? Also what's the difference between using FacebookClient and FacebookWebClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config file you also have to set:

```
<facebookSettings appSecret="your app secret" appId="your app id" />
```

and to get the current user:

```
var facebookApp = new FacebookApp();
facebookApp.Api("/4");
```

Comment: I still get the same error with this in there, plus also I'm passing it in manually to my FacebookClient instance above. Where can I get hold of this authtoken and pass it in?

Comment: Also when i do facebookApp.Api("/4"); its bringing back Mark Zukerberg (lol) I assume that the default one. but facebookApp.Get() returns the (OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user